# Make items in a flexbox take up all vertical and horizontal space

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I currently have elements within a container, each of which contains an image. I want to distribute these into the four corners or the container, using flexbox. The images are distributing correctly horizontally, but don't take up all the available space vertically.

Here's what it looks like at the moment: [image]

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/180">
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/180">
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/180">
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/180">
    </div>
</div>
```

And my (S)CSS:

```
div.container {
    width: 405px;
    height: 405px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;

    div.photo {
        width: 180px;
        height: 180px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-radius: 5px;

        img {
            height: 100%;
        }                   
    }
}
```

```css
div.container {
  width: 405px;
  height: 405px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div.container div.photo {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

div.container div.photo img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/180">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/180">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/180">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/180">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apply `align-content: space-between` to your `flexbox` to do that (this assumes of course that you have sufficient *available* space for the *vertical alignment*)- see demo below:

> The align-content property modifies the behavior of the flex-wrap
>   property. It is similar to align-items, but instead of aligning flex
>   items, it aligns flex lines.
>   (Source: [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-content.asp))

```css
div.container {
  width: 405px;
  height: 405px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
}
div.container div.photo {
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/180">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/180">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/180">
  </div>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/180">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution leads the flexmodel into the absurd. The result is a static size. Flex should be there to deal with dynamic variables. For this result, flex is unnecessary.

Comment: Upvote show a valid solution. But this is a not a one. Sorry

Comment: @JanNahody This is a *valid* one for God's sake!! please read about `align-content` and why its used!

Comment: Flex has been made to deal with dynamic variables. Your solution provides a valid solution for this. This is not correct, however, since it can not deal with dynamic variables. It is a solution, but NOT a flex solution. This is the reason for my acting.

Comment: Add this limitation to your answer and I will up vote it.

Comment: @JanNahody *This* answer is about *distributing the vertical space* and `flexbox` does that with `align-content` when there are multiple flex items that wrap, see what I mean?

Comment: set height to 100% and you will see what I mean. Your suggestion work only on fix sizes.

Comment: @JanNahody well, added the *limitation* to the answer - but I guess that's how `flexbox` works... well, now you can revert the down vote I presume...

Comment: @JanNahody Thanks!

Comment: I like your attitude. With pleasure

Comment: @kukkuz seems like you had a pretty hard time in this comments section ! (tough crowd i guess) anyways thanks for your answer !