# How do I give margin to image using flexbox?

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I want the images to have margin, so I wrote the `justify-content: space-around` but there is no margin between the top images and the bottom images.

```css
  
#portfolio {
  background-color: #00C3A9;
  height: 800px;
}
.portfolio_pic {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="portfolio">  
  <div class="portfolio_pic">
 <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
 <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
 <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
 <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
 <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
 <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

What can I do in this case? Thank you

Comment: margins should be set to children, there is no other ways to set 'gutters' in between flex wrapped rows. display:grid; has this option (grid-gap) , not flex. ;) `.portfolio_pic img {margin:X;}` is the most coherent way to achieve this in my own humble opinion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you are trying to do is getting *space* between the *flex lines* of the `flexbox` (see a [`related issue here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912941/make-items-in-a-flexbox-take-up-all-vertical-and-horizontal-space/40913025#40913025) if you are interested) - so you can do add these rules:

1. `align-content: space-around` to vertically space the *flex lines*
2. `height: 100%` to occupy the height of the `portfolio` div.

See demo below:

```css
#portfolio {
  background-color: #00C3A9;
  height: 800px;
}
.portfolio_pic {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-around;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="portfolio_pic">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works only when there is enough space for all image tags. When space is limited, the vertical spacing is gone.

Comment: @JanNahody that depends on what OP want to manage when space is limited - to *overflow* or not...

Comment: Flex should be there to deal with dynamic variables. Here the OP have to set fix sizes. Sorry this is no solution for flex. Using fix sizes we do not need flex.

Answer (score 3):

You could try adding a margin to your images like so

```
img { margin-top: 15px; }
```

Or create a class with that style like so, and give each image that class:

```
.imagesingrid { margin-top: 15px; }
<img class="imagesingrid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
```

Answer (score 2):

Flex is one dimensional. So when you use `justify-content: space-around` it manage it in defined dimension. row or column.
Any reason not giving margin to image element?

```css
#portfolio {
  background-color: #00C3A9;
  height: 800px;
}
.portfolio_pic {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="portfolio">  
  <div class="portfolio_pic">
 <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
 <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
 <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
 <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
 <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
 <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x300" alt="">
</div>
</div>
```